# Php Mysqli_fetch_assoc Error : "Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in"

Tags: php, mysqli

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection\index.php on line 31
>   1",

Please can anyone help me.

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
```

and in Body tag

```
<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo $row['name'];
}?>
```

Comment: Try `while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`, instead of your `foreach`, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) here to get all rows within `$rows` at once.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rows); // Check your result
```

Comment: Hi,can you please help me out in using with foreach loop.

Comment: thank, its working fine. but one more help, when i use while loop to display 'name ' it's fine, but if i used foreach to loop , then this error occured.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the results in array and use it in the body as follow:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

and in Body tag

```
<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
 echo $row['name'];
}?>
```